# SQL pattern recognition, exclude last few characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have two tables with columns `a`, `b`:

```
| t1.column a          | t2.Column b  
| ---------------------| --------- |
| varchar [00000000]   |00000002-03| 
| varchar [00000001]   |00000000-01| 
| varchar [00000002]   |00000001-01|
```

I want to collect all values from column `a` that match values in column `b` ignoring the last three characters '-00'.

My result should look like:

```
|       a              |     b  
| ---------------------| --------- |
| varchar [00000000]   |00000000-01| 
| varchar [00000001]   |00000001-01| 
| varchar [00000002]   |00000002-03|
```

My query:

```
select
 t1.column_a
,t2.column_b
,etc
from t1,t2
where column_a like '%column_b%'
```

I get nothing because of the formatting of column `b`.

What I'd ideally like to do is match column `a` to ('%column b%' minus those last three characters).
Any ideas?

Comment: this should work in ANSI SQL:
where t2.column_b like (t1.column_a || '%')

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `split_part()`:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.column_a = split_part(t2.column_b, '-', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('SQL Tutorial', 1, 3) FROM table;
```

result: SQL

so perhaps

```
select
t1.column_a
t2.column_b
from t1,t2
where column_a IN (select SUBSTRING (t2.column_b,1,8) from t1,t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use like for some reason:

```
select * from t1 join t2 on t2.b like concat('%', t1.a, '%');
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/244ee/1)

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd ideally like to do is match column `a` to *('%column b%' minus those last three characters)*

```sql
SELECT t1.column_a, t2.column_b
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.column_a = left(t2.column_b, -3);
```